# Max RAM in Windows Server R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, memory

Is the maximum memory for Windows Server R2 Web/Standard only 32GB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, if you have need of an application that requires more than 32 GB of active ram you need enterprise or datacenter.  That being said those applications are few and far between.

Answer (score 6):

Yes.

Heres a link to an MSDN [technote](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_server_2008_r2) on it.